# Selenium WebDriver connection to Kameleo browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, kameleo

So I have figured out how to get started and open a Kameleo browser profile using Python. However, I find the Session ID and Port the chrome browser was started with. I think I have this, but my session ID is throwing an error.

I was expecting the `/profiles/{guid}/start` endpoint would return a JSON dictionary with the session id and port, also would be nice to have that under the `profiles/{guid}/status` http calls. I couldn't find it in the [swaggerhub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/kameleo-team/kameleo-local-api/2.3) documentation.

This is the code I'm using

```
from kameleo.local_api_client.kameleo_local_api_client import KameleoLocalApiClient
from kameleo.local_api_client.builder_for_create_profile import BuilderForCreateProfile

client = KameleoLocalApiClient()
base_profiles = client.search_base_profiles(
    device_type='desktop',
    browser_product='chrome'
)

# Create a new profile with recommended settings
# for browser fingerprinting protection
create_profile_request = BuilderForCreateProfile \
    .for_base_profile(base_profiles[0].id) \
    .set_recommended_defaults() \
    .build()
profile = client.create_profile(body=create_profile_request)

# Start the browser
client.start_profile(profile.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you don't need to get the port and the sessionID manually as you can make the connection to the browser through Kameleo.CLI.exe  port.

If you keep on reading the [README](https://github.com/kameleo-io/local-api-client-python#automate-browsers-with-w3c-webdriver) you will find an example where they showcase the W3C WebDriver connection.

```
# Connect to the running browser instance using WebDriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("kameleo:profileId", profile.id)
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=f'{kameleoBaseUrl}/webdriver',
    options=options
)

# Use any WebDriver command to drive the browser
# and enjoy full protection from Selenium detection methods
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

I could also find this code in [Kameleo's example repository](https://github.com/kameleo-io/local-api-examples/blob/master/python/connect_to_selenium/app.py).

Comment: To use the webdriver variable in the example, first run `pip install selenium` then `from selenium import webdriver`